# What is the difference between the count and the gauge metric type in DataDog?

Tags: datadog

What is the difference between the [count](https://docs.datadoghq.com/developers/metrics/types/?tab=count) and the [gauge](https://docs.datadoghq.com/developers/metrics/types/?tab=gauge) metric types in DataDog? Or rather, when should I prefer one over the other? The definitions from their website don't help me much:

Count:

> The COUNT metric submission type represents the total number of event occurrences in one time interval. A COUNT can be used to track the total number of connections made to a database or the total number of requests to an endpoint. This number of events can accumulate or decrease over time—it is not monotonically increasing.

Gauge:

> The GAUGE metric submission type represents a snapshot of events in one time interval. This representative snapshot value is the last value submitted to the Agent during a time interval. A GAUGE can be used to take a measure of something reporting continuously—like the available disk space or memory used.

The `count` type seems to be somewhat related to the [`rate`](https://docs.datadoghq.com/developers/metrics/types/?tab=rate) type, but for me it is unclear why or when I should use `count` instead of `gauge`. I mean in principle a measurement of "something" could always be presented as a gauge, couldn't it?

Answer (score 15):

The [datadog doc](https://docs.datadoghq.com/metrics/types/?tab=count#metric-types) gives clear examples about their differences:

###### Count

> Suppose you are submitting a COUNT metric, activeusers.basket_size, from a single host running the Datadog Agent. This host emits the following values in a flush time interval: [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3].
>
> The Agent adds all the values received in one time interval and submits the total number, in this case 15, as the COUNT metric’s value.

###### Gauge

> Suppose you are submitting a GAUGE metric, temperature, from a single host running the Datadog Agent. This host emits the following values in a flush time interval: [71,71,71,71,71,71,71.5].
>
> The Agent submits the last reported number, in this case 71.5, as the GAUGE metric’s value.

Essentially, in a flush time interval, usually [10s](https://docs.datadoghq.com/developers/dogstatsd/data_aggregation/#how-is-aggregation-performed-with-the-dogstatsd-server), Count accumulates all values and submit the sum value, while Gauge only keeps the latest one because it's a snapshot, and it also consumes less resource.

One good example for Count is that we want to know how many 404 happens in a certain time period, in this scenario, the sum matters. One good example for Gauge is that we want to check the memory usage of a server, 10s, the default flush interval, is sufficient to get one particular snapshot about it.